# Did some of my answers recently get deleted?

Tags: support

I did a rep recalc yesterday (for the first time in three days) and lost 55 rep.  Curious, I found that my number of answers in my profile page went down by 4.  Putting 55 and 4 together, I came up with 59, which means I come here to ask if a moderator can view recently deleted answers to figure this out.

Comment: Wait, are you summing the reputation you lost with the number of answers you think are missing? Uh?

Comment: 2+2=4 didn't well apply here.  I'll change it to that, though, if the metaphor is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did delete several dozen closed questions that were of low quality, many of which had at least one upvoted answer. Looking through your answers, I see the following answers deleted because the question was:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34085/why-is-it-called-a-hamburger-when-its-actually-made-from-beef/ (75 rep)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34553/an-representation/34555#34555 (30 rep)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34603/is-the-sentence-i-am-right-grammatically-correct/34626#34626 (10 rep)

I don't see a fourth deleted answer, but I may have missed it. In any case, it looks like you may have lost 125 rep and not 55, depending on when you did the recalc yesterday (in any case, you would lose the remaining balance upon another recalc).

Comment: Ouch!  Oh well; if I can't take that, I don't deserve what I have left. :-)

Comment: @waiwai--Sorry to highjack the thread, but did this happen to a few of my older answers too?

Comment: @simchona Yes—I distinctly remember seeing your username at least twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you lost reputation, and you count 4 answers less than you asked, then there are just two possibilities: Four questions to which you answered were deleted, or four answers you gave have been deleted. Between the two possibilities, I think the first is more probable.

As to the answers that has been deleted, I found the following one:

- [Should I use 'cards' or 'a card'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39095/should-i-use-cards-or-a-card/39146#39146) (score: 0)

Comment: Yes, well, that I deleted.  But it didn't lose me any rep.  Oh well, it's very little to worry about - I just wondered.